# Using PHP,how to insert a line efficient to the end of a very large .txt file

Tags: php, text

the .txt  file is about 500M,when i use fopen,my computer just can not work,so i wanna any other way to finish the task

Comment: Are you on Linux? If so, are you against using the shell to achieve this?

Comment: `fopen` by itself is not the problem. Show your code.

Comment: I doubt that's due to fopen, because what fopen does is generate a pointer to the file and a cursor at the beginning of the file. The size of the file should have little to no effect on performance. Seeking inside the file should again have little to no performance issues. Surprisingly, so does appending to the file! Show us what have you tried! And we might be inclined to help.

Comment: `fopen()` with mode `'a'` will open in Append mode. Use that; you won't have to read the existing file contents; you can just write the new content to the end of the file. Pretty standard stuff.

Comment: thanks to you all kind helper.i am on win server 08,use 'a'mode(mentioned above) is the best solution,thansk again

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 $fp = fopen( "file.txt", 'a' );
 fwrite( $fp, "\n" );
 fclose( $fp );
```

Comment: agreed. what's wrong with this? `fopen()` with mode `'a'` is Append mode, which meand the new content is just appended to the end of the file; it doesn't matter what the file size is because the existing data in the file is never read.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running PHP script on Linux, you can do it with:

```
$newLine  = 'some text';
$filename = 'large.txt';
system('echo "' . $newLine . '" >> ' . $filename);
```

Comment: thanks to you all guys,i have solved the question by change fopen mode to 'a'(append),